# Second order recurrence relation with $\delta$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question is: "2y(n)-y(n-1)-2y(n-2)=delta(n-2)   find y(n)"

What might the teacher wants as a result? He didn't teach us any similar thing. My attempt on solving the question was like this:

Procedure:

[image]

Canceling:

[image]

EndResult:

[image]

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  What does "delta(n-2)" mean?

Comment: @lulu Are you asking the OP whether he/she knows that $\delta(n-2)$ denotes a quantity which is $1$ when $n=2$ and $0$ otherwise ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  Well, yes.  If that's what was intended here, which was not obvious to me.  As far as I can see, the sketched work just assumes it is some unknown function.

Comment: To be honest question is given this way. I was asking to myself this too, but I thing it is not important in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference equation given is

$2y_n - y_{n-1} - 2 y_{n-2} = \delta(n - 2) $

Shift the index by $+2$, you get

$2y_{n+2}- y_{n+1} - 2 y_{n} = \delta(n) $

which is a difference equation of second order.  The characteristic polynomial is

$ 2 x^2 - x - 2 = 0 $

Its roots are

$ x_1 =  \dfrac{1}{4} ( 1 - \sqrt{17} ) $

$ x_2 =  \dfrac{1}{4} ( 1 + \sqrt{17} ) $

A particular solution is $y_n = -\dfrac{1}{2} \delta(n) $

Thus the overall solution is

$ y_n = A (x_1)^n + B (x_2)^n - \dfrac{1}{2} \delta(n) $

Now imposing the initial conditions,

$y_0 = A + B - \dfrac{1}{2} $

$y_1 = A x_1 + B x_2  $

Solving for $A$ and $B$ we obtain,

$A = \dfrac{ x_2 (y_0 + \frac{1}{2}) - y_1 }{x_2 - x_1} $

$B = \dfrac{ -x_1 ( y_0 + \frac{1}{2}) + y_1 } { x_2 - x_1 } $

Comment: Sorry if it is a silly question, but did you solve this to find y(n)" or in other words (d^2y/dx^2)? Question is to find y(n)? It is like find y(x). n's in the equation is not under y, they are inside parentheses.  Question is in other way like this: 2y(x)-y(x-1)-2y(x-2)=delta(x-2) find y(x)

Comment: What I have found is $y(n)$ which I wrote as $y_n$, they are the same thing.

Comment: $y $ is a sequence that is a function of the index variable $n$.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I will look it up. Thank you for the answer.